# Fourier–Stieltjes as the dual space of the full group algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

I know that this fact is classical, but I can't find the proof of it. How to proof that $B(G)=(C^*(G))^*$? As I understood, I can take a functional $F: \ell_1(G) \to \mathbb{C}$, and there is one-to-one correspondence with B(G) by using the formula $F(f)=<f,g>=\sum f(t)g(t), f \in l^1(G), g \in B(G)$. But why does it works not only for the functionals on $\ell_1(G)$, but for the functionals on $C^*(G)$ also?

Comment: What are you taking as your definition of $B(G)$? If you are defining it as the set of coefficient functions of continuous unitary representations, then the result should follow from the correspondence between cts unitary reps of G and *-reps of $C^\ast(G)$. If you are defining it as the linear span of the continuous positive definite functions, I think the proof is in Eymard's original paper.

Comment: I take the following definition of B(G): It is the space of  $f:G \to B(H)$ such that there is a Hilbert space, and a unitary representation $\pi: G \to B(H)$ and elements $x,y \in H$ such that $f(t)=<\pi(t)x,y>$..

Comment: I think this is best viewed as combination of two facts. The first is that unitary representations of $G$ are interchangeable with representations of $C^*(G)$ (proved using $L^1(G)$). This can be found in e.g. Dixmier 13.9.3. The second is the extended version of the GNS correspondence for C*-algebras that applies also to non-positive linear functionals. I don't have a reference for this, but it can be proved using the polar decomposition of a linear functional (in the enveloping W*-algebra). There may be an easier way.

Comment: @RobertFurber I think this is the standard approach. One possible reference is the MSc thesis of C. Zwarich https://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/handle/10012/3920 -- see Proposition 2.12.14 and the remarks before it.

Comment: @YemonChoi Thanks for that. Corollary 3.6.4, occuring later, is what I had in mind with polar decompositions.